# What is difference between React's this.setState call in class component and useState hook in functional component?

Tags: reactjs

What is difference between React's this.setState call in class component and useState hook in functional component?

I tried to understand how setting state in functional component using useState hook is synchronous whereas setState call in calss component is asyncronous.

Comment: *"I tried to understand how setting state in functional component using useState hook is synchronous"* - It isn't.  Aside from that misunderstanding... Can you clarify what exactly you're asking?  Do you have an example of code which isn't doing what you expect in some way?

Answer (score 1):

The `useState` hook is basically "the fragmented version of `setState`".

Classed components have a single `this.state` state variable that you asynchronously push updates to using `this.setState(objectWithUpdates)`. There is one state. The end.

The `useState` hook instead gives you *as many separate state variables as you need* so that you're not constantly updating a single, monolithic state representation, but specifically only variables that need updating, which you then typically use as dependencies for effects, callbacks, memoized functions, etc. etc.

Of course, in terms of what they can do and how they're used, there is no real difference. The render pass doesn't care in the slightest whether it's templating `<h1>this.state.welcomeMessage}</h1>` or whether it's templating `<h1>{welcomeMessage</h1>`, a `useEffect` hook doesn't care whether the dependency array is `[this.state.count]` or `[count]`, etc. etc.

They're simply two ways to do the same thing, one specific to "when using classes" and the other specific to "when using function components".